# Dynamic Home Page based on Log in status

Tags: membership, members, s2member, plugin-members

I want to build the home page to show just a login box when logged out and the normal home page when logged in.

Alternatively i can also allow redirection to another page when a logged in user clicks home.

I am using WP membership plugin for membership access.

Thanks

Comment: Tried playing with a few plugins, like redirect after login, but none actually permanently redirected a logged in user from the home page. My research found that there is no way to do this without actually editing the theme files, but i wanted to keep a child theme as a last resort.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can put this on your in your home page template or in your header.php (if you want to use across your entire site).

```
<?php 
if ( !is_user_logged_in() ) {
    auth_redirect();
}
?>
```

Details in the Wordpress codex... https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/auth_redirect